# spring pass the object to the jsf view

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I have a class that is mostly populated with the data from Facebook, however missing two attributes that have to be filled from coming from a form data.

This is the form: `central/cadastro.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:body> 
    <h:graphicImage value="https://graph.facebook.com/${usuario.id}/picture" /> Olá, ${usuario.firstName} ${usuario.lastName}
    <h:form id="formCadastro" prependId="false"> 
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            Login: <h:inputText label="Login" value="#{usuarioFacebook.userid}" /> 
            Senha: <h:inputSecret label="Senha" value="#{usuarioFacebook.password}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="${usuarioFacebookDAO.persist(usuario)}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form> 
</h:body> 
</html>
```

This form is displayed through `ModelAndView` the spring * * method, passing an object of type`UsuarioFacebook` with the name of `usuario`:

```
@RequestMapping("/loginfbresponse")
public ModelAndView logarComFacebook(String code) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

  UsuarioFacebook userFB = loginFacebook.obterUsuarioFacebook(code);
    System.out.println("Buscando email " + userFB.getEmail() + " no banco...");
      UsuarioFacebook userFBDB = usuarioFacebookDAO.find(userFB.getId());
      if(userFBDB == null){
        if(userFB.getVerified()){
          //usuarioFacebookDAO.persist(userFB);
          System.out.println("Usuário " + userFB.getEmail() + " foi direcionado para cadastro.");

          ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("central/cadastro");
          mv.addObject("usuario", userFB);
          return mv;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Usuário " + userFB.getEmail() + " não é uma conta ativa.");
          ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("central/containvalida");
          return mv;
        }                    
      } else {
        System.out.println("Usuário " + userFB.getEmail() + " foi encontrado!");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("central/home");
        mv.addObject("usuario", userFBDB);
        return mv;
      }
}
```

the return is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` since`commandButton` does not pass the object `usuario` to the`persist ()`, why?

Both `UsuarioFacebookDAO` as UsuarioFacebook`are noted as`ManagedBean`.

Comment: Both `ModelAndView` and `RequestMapping` are Spring MVC artifacts. How would you be able to use them in conjunction with JSF? What does this EL do `action="${usuarioFacebookDAO.persist(usuario)}"`? (Here and in `<h:graphicImage>` too, `$` is not a problem but it should always be `#` while using Facelets).

Comment: Correct! I changed all the `$` to `#` but the operation of the page has not changed.
`action = "# {UsuarioFacebookDAO.persist(usuario)}"` the `usuario` object in the past `persist` is an object created by `ModelAndView.AddObject`, it seems that JSF does not recognize it returns `NullPointerException`